# s3 upload always timeout in normal bindwidth

Tags: amazon-s3, timeout, multipart

in order to make the issue clear, I prepared a specific repo(https://github.com/mlhch/s3test/) and live page(http://mlhch.github.io/s3test/) for testing.

In short, uploading a large file in browser by using AWS S3 Multipart Upload javascript SDK often fails due to a network timeout error. But as tested it can succeed in EC2 instance and other cloud machines such as Sauce Labs.

I really couldn't figure out where is the issue...